# How i can use DFS with a final state automata in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, depth-first-search, finite-automata, dcg

I have a final state automata and i want to see all the patterns. This automata is about morphology of Turkish.

Turkish is an agglutinative language. I analyze words and and find their morphemes and allomorphs.

For example:

```
?- analyze('kediler', Allomorphs, Morphemes).
Allomorphs = [kedi, ler],
Morphemes  = [noun, plur]
```

An example about my final state automata:

```
final(qv4b).
final(qv4c).
final(qv5).
final(qv5a).

% First Step
t(q0,noun,qn1).
t(q0,verb,qv1).
```

[A part of the graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5saSY.png)

I have issues about some points therefore the results are wrong. I have to test word by word and morpheme by morpheme myself. I want to create a Deep First Search algorithm and see all the results.

What path should I follow in order to do this?

Comment: In any case, consider [tag:dcg]

Comment: `s/final/finite/`